# Error when attempting to change child div properities

Tags: javascript, html, tags, children

I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` on the line `document.getElementById(blueChild).style.border = "2px solid white"` and I've looked on-line and haven't found a solution. Here is my code:

```
var scroller = function(direction, team){
    console.log("scrolling")
    if (team == "blue"){
        if (direction == "left"){
            blueCount = blueCount - 1
        }

        if (blueCount < 0){
            blueCount = 3
        }
        if (redCount < 0){
            redCount = 3    
        }

        var blueChildren = document.getElementById('blueSelector').getElementsByTagName('div')
        var blueChild = blueChildren[blueCount]
        document.getElementById(blueChild).style.border = "2px solid white"

        for (var i = 0; i < blueChildren.length; i++){
            if (i !== blueCount){
                blueChild = blueChildren[i]
                document.getElementById(blueChild).style.border = "2px solid black"
            }
        }
    }
}

scroller("left", "blue")
```

By the way, `blueCount`, `redCount` have global defaults of `0`

Much requested HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="rectangle.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">You're browser does not support the canvas tag. Go and get a real browser, nub</canvas>
    <div id="redSelector">
        <div class="genericButton" id="zombieRed">Zombie</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="skeletonRed">Skeleton</div>
         <div class="genericButton" id="creeperRed">Creeper</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="spideBlue">Spider</div>
    </div>
    <div id="blueSelector">
        <div class="genericButton" id="zombieBlue">Zombie</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="skeletonBlue">Skeleton</div>
         <div class="genericButton" id="creeperBlue">Creeper</div>
        <div class="genericButton" id="spiderBlue">Spider</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What i am trying to achieve is assessing the child elements of `blueSelector` and making one coloured with a white border and rest with a black border.

Comment: Consider semicolons. If nothing else, it makes your code easier to interpret.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Post a complete code example please.

Comment: `document.getElementById(blueChild)` returns null. Otherwise, this line should be working.  Check again the spelling of the ID, and execute separately the command `document.getElementById(blueChild)` to verify it is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution! turns out i defined `blueCount` using `var blueCount` and when i used the variable as an index in my array of `blueChildren`, `blueCount` is `undefined` and the `blueChild` is then undefined.

Hope people learn from my silly mistakes xD

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do this:

```
blueChild.style.border = "2px solid white"
```

and

```
blueChild.style.border = "2px solid black"
```

Because the `blueChild` variable you created points to an HTML element, not a String representing the ID.

**Edit**: Oh, and you forgot a quote:

```
               here
                 ↓
scroller("left", "blue")
```

Comment: Dosent work. I now get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: @JammehCarr I edited my answer, you seem to have forgotten a quote

Comment: I added HTML, can you now awnser you're question according to that?

Comment: @JammehCarr It works fine when you change what I said: http://jsfiddle.net/4rpyqmb8/

Comment: But you need the document to be loaded. Put your `<script>` tag right above the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: What do you mean? The document IS loaded.

Comment: Yes, but the HTML divs need to be before your script, so move your script tag right before the closing body tag, because if if executes too early, the document won't be finished loading yet.

Comment: I dont think thats the case because in my full code i actually activate the `scroller` function alot later after the script is loaded